# Как сделать в Unity так, чтобы функция выполнялась в течении n секунд?

Tags: unity3d

К примеру, есть две функции, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы они обе выполнялись в течении `1 (2, 3, 10, 100, ..)` секунд. Т.е чтобы значение `start` из первой функции достигло `100` в то же самое время, что и значение `start` из второй функции достигло `9000`

```
void FuncOne()
{
    int start = 0;
    int fin = 100;

    if (start < 101)
        start++;
}

void FuncTwo()
{
    int start = 0;
    int fin = 9000;

    if (start < 9001)
        start++;
}
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что можно воспользоваться корутинами, но не могу сообразить, как именно

---

Обновление:

Я хочу сделать красивую анимацию увеличения значения циферок и уложить ее в три секунды (или в две, если три - слишком долго). И таких функций должно быть несколько - сначала выполняется первая с "анимацией" увеличения циферок от начального значения до заданного максимального, проходит секунда, выполняется вторая, еще через секунду третья и так далее. Все функции вызываются только один раз в сцене, но при каждом ее запуске. Т.е начальные значения и значения, к которым они должны придти, каждый раз разные

---

Обновление 2:

При старте уровня у меня сохраняется текущее значение `Points`. В процессе прохождения уровня добавляются `Points` и при этом записываются отдельно - вот эти очки за это действие, а вот эти - за это. В итоге в конце уровня у меня есть (условно) `Points 1` - очки, которые были при запуске уровня; `Points 2` - количество очков, набранное за действия `А`; `Points 3` - количество очков, набранное за действия `Б`; `Points 4` - общее количество очков, полученное из `Points 1 + Points 2 + Points 3`. Все это есть, а вот следующего еще нет. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы на экране `Points 1` за три секунды увеличивался до `Points 1 + Points 2` (пусть она будет `Points 1,2`), потом пауза две секунды, затем `Points 1,2` должен за три секунды увеличиться до `Points 1 + Points 2 + Points 3`, потом опять пауза две секунда, а затем полученное число должно увеличиться до `Points 4`.

Comment: `чтобы значение start из первой функции достигло 100 в то же самое время, что и значение start из второй функции достигло 9000` - это невозможно, потому что `start` это начало и оно не должно изменяться.....`Что-то мне подсказывает, что можно воспользоваться корутинами, но не могу сообразить, как именно` - а мне что-то подсказывает, что ты хочешь слепить какой-то непонятный костыль)) и в итоге у тебя **[Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191482)** ...... лучше скажи, что нужно сделать (функциональность), а не то, что ты думаешь, что надо сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский обновил вопрос

Comment: Расписывай еще подробнее, все равно не понятно, что требуется. Несколько функций(зачем?), почему они должны запускаться подряд и делать одно и тоже ? Что значит "увеличения значения циферок"?(может числа?) Эти функции над одним тем же числом или над разными?  Если хочешь, чтобы помогали, описывай понятнее задачу.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ расписал еще подробнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Points 1,2` должен за три секунды увеличиться до `Points 1 + Points 2 + Points 3` , потом опять пауза две секунда, а затем полученное число должно увеличиться до Points 4
>
> Points 4 - общее количество очков, полученное из Points 1 + Points 2 +
>   Points 3

Разве выше сказанное не противоречит друг другу?(по сути `Points 4=Points 1 + Points 2 + Points 3`).

Короче не понятно сколько и чего тебе надо прибавить, вот "я сделяль" для n-го количества тех самых `Points`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Test2 : MonoBehaviour {

    struct Record
    {
        public float Points;//Наши Points
        public float NextWaitTimer;//Ожидание перед следующим прибавлением Points
        public float InnerTimer;//Время "красивой анимации с циферками"
    }

    public Text TestLog;
    float FullPoints;//Общее количество Points
    Record[] records;

    private void Start()
    {
        records = GetRecords();
        if(records.Length>0) StartCoroutine(RecordsInit());
    }
    Record[] GetRecords()//каким то образом получаем все свои числа со временем ожидания для каждого
    {
        return new Record[]
        {
            new Record { Points=100, InnerTimer=2f, NextWaitTimer=0.5f },
            new Record { Points=200, InnerTimer=2f, NextWaitTimer=2f },
            new Record { Points=300, InnerTimer=2f, NextWaitTimer=2f }
        };
    }

    IEnumerator RecordsInit()
    {
        YieldInstruction yi = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        Record LastRecord = records[0];
        FullPoints = LastRecord.Points;
        TestLog.text = ((int)FullPoints).ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(LastRecord.NextWaitTimer);
        for (int i=1;i< records.Length;i++)
        {
            LastRecord = records[i];
            float cur = 0f;
            if (LastRecord.InnerTimer > 0f) {
                while (cur< LastRecord.Points)
                {
                    cur += LastRecord.Points * (Time.deltaTime / LastRecord.InnerTimer);//Time.unscaledDeltaTime
                    TestLog.text = ((int)(FullPoints+ cur)).ToString();
                    yield return yi;
                }
            }
            FullPoints += LastRecord.Points;
            TestLog.text = ((int)FullPoints).ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(LastRecord.NextWaitTimer);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, делает то, что нужно. Но что делать, если количество `new Record { Points=100, InnerTimer=2f, NextWaitTimer=0.5f },
            new Record { Points=200, InnerTimer=2f, NextWaitTimer=2f },
            new Record { Points=300, InnerTimer=2f, NextWaitTimer=2f }` может быть разным? Например, при одном запуске `new Record` две штуки, а при другом запуске их целых пять?

Comment: @KremSoda Ну сделай вместо массива - лист, и добавляй динамически сколько потребуется